# How can I fix these errors

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I wrote a simple app that shows something where you enter a username with the right password, but I get an error message that I don't really understand.....

***The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions**

*
My Code:
`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var buttonO = false
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var v1 = false
    @State private var v2 = false

    
    var body: some View {   <--The compiler is unable to type-check this expression....
        
        VStack{
            TextField(
                    "User name",
                    text: $username)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .border(Color(UIColor.separator))
                SecureField(
                    "Password",
                    text: $password
                ) {
                }
                .border(Color(UIColor.separator))
            
            if username == "admin" {v1.toggle()}
            if password == 123 {v2.toggle()}
            
            if v1 && v2 == true {
                Text("Krabben Bürger Geheimformel...   H=ode2X")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

`

I didn't try much because I didn't understand the error itself

Comment: The error is not a good one, but the problem is the two lines starting with `if username == "admin" {v1.toggle()}` -- you can't have procedural code like this in your view hierarchy. Something like that should go in a button action, or something like that.

Comment: Sometimes the Swift compiler generates REALLY awful error messages. This is such a time. When that happens you have to treat the error message as if they say “there is something wrong with your code. You figure it out.” In this case jnpdx told you the cause.

Comment: The error is happening because the code is mixing the compilation time description of how to construct the view with logic about how manipulate its runtime state in the wrong place, i.e. it's trying to change `@State` vars in the `body` layout definition, and the compiler doesn't know what to do with it. One fix would be to use an `onChange` for `username` and one for `password` and set `v1` and `v2` state vars there. Better, might be to replace `v1 and `v2` with a computed prop something like `var adminShow: Bool { if username ... && ... { return true } return false } and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments under your question they will answer to your question.
But to help you out a bit, you could try something like that :)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var stringToDisplay: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("User name", text: $username)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .border(Color(.separator))
            
            SecureField("Password", text: $password) { }
                .border(Color(.separator))
            
            Button("Submit") {
                if username == "admin", password == "123" {
                    stringToDisplay = "Krabben Bürger Geheimformel...   H=ode2X"
                }
            }
            
            Text(stringToDisplay)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```